# How to exclude a folder from a KDevelop project?

Tags: development, ide, kdevelop

Currently my `o` folder is appearing in my KDevelop project tree, and therefore `.o` files appear in the *open file* completion list.

Is there a way to exclude certain folders from KDevelop's view of the project?

I'm using KDevelop 4.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `.kdev_ignore` file to the folder which you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks very much, works perfectly (after restarting KDevelop.) Do you know if it's possible to exclude files whose names match a pattern?

Comment: Sorry, have no idea